# Python appending each integer in list to each integer in another list

Tags: python

Noob here, Okay so i want to append each integer generated from "range(3,20)" to another similar range "range(22,40)

```
from itertools import chain

L1 = 3
H1 = 20
L2 = 22
H2 = 40

new_list = [x for x in chain(range(L1,H1))]
new_list2 = [xx for xx in chain(range(L2,H2))]
print (new_list + new_list2)
```

Results should be:

```
322
323
324
325...
422
423
424
425...
```

Current results from above code:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
```

Comment: Note: this is not the actual range. It is much bigger, so if someone knows of a more efficient way, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
L1, H1 = 3, 20
L2, H2 = 22, 40

new_list = [int(str(a) + str(b)) for a in range(L1, H1) for b in range(L2, H2)]
print(new_list)

# [322, 323, ..., 339, 422, 423, ..., 439, 522, ..., 939, 1022, 1023, ..., 1939]
```

It's a kind of hacky workaround for your kind of hacky use case: for each pair of numbers `a` and `b` from your two ranges, we

1. Convert `a` and `b` to strings
2. Concatenate them (so `a=3` and `b=22` produces `'322'`)
3. Convert the result back into an integer

Comment: Okay so i tried the line below since memory will be an issue but still ran into MemoryError.      new_list = tuple((int(str(a) + str(b)) for a,b in itertools.product(range(L1, H1), range(L2, H2))))

Comment: If your goal is to *print out the numbers*, rather than *store them*, then don't do `tuple`. Just do `new_list = (int(str(a) + str(b)) for a in range(L1, H1) for b in range(L2, H2))` - with just the parentheses, and not a `tuple()`, it produces a generator that doesn't take constant memory. Thereafter you can do a for loop: `for n in new_list: print(n)`

Comment: i'm getting "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x019610B0>" as a result

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about the product of two lists, so an itertools solution would look like:

```
[int(str(a) + str(b)) for a,b in itertools.product(range(L1, H1), range(L2, H2))]
```

Note that your `chain` is superfluous and can simply be dropped. Also, if the ranges are large so that memory becomes an issue, you could use the generator expression

```
(int(str(a) + str(b)) for a,b in itertools.product(range(L1, H1), range(L2, H2)))
```

since in many ways the point of `itertools` is to allow for memory-efficient iteration.